# How to get the pid number which connect to external ip?

Tags: netstat

Some program was connected from my local ip 111.111.111.111 with 130.239.18.176:80,how to get the pid number?

```
 netstat  -np
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 111.111.111.111:46243    52.89.80.240:443        TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      1 111.111.111.111:36553    173.239.79.210:443      SYN_SENT    2630/firefox-esr
tcp        0      0 111.111.111.111:48470    130.239.18.176:80       ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      1 111.111.111.111:36552    173.239.79.210:443      SYN_SENT    2630/firefox-esr
tcp        0      1 111.111.111.111:34202    74.125.204.101:80       SYN_SENT    2630/firefox-esr
tcp        0      0 111.111.111.111:52243    203.208.48.79:443       ESTABLISHED 2630/firefox-esr
tcp        0      1 111.111.111.111:46521    74.125.203.93:443       SYN_SENT    2630/firefox-esr
tcp        0      1 111.111.111.111:34200    74.125.204.101:80       SYN_SENT    2630/firefox-esr
tcp        0      0 111.111.111.111:48424    130.239.18.176:80       ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 111.111.111.111:46238    52.89.80.240:443        TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      1 111.111.111.111:46523    74.125.203.93:443       SYN_SENT    2630/firefox-esr
tcp        0      0 111.111.111.111:34204    74.125.204.101:80       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 111.111.111.111:33700    104.24.98.177:443       ESTABLISHED 2630/firefox-esr
tcp        0      1 111.111.111.111:34206    74.125.204.101:80       SYN_SENT    2630/firefox-esr
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:49941         127.0.0.1:80            ESTABLISHED 2630/firefox-esr
```

Comment: Like the message says: "you would have to be root to see it all". Try `sudo netstat -np`.

Comment: The quoted block has a PID column already - and no edition log?. Are we still looking for something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `netstat` output explains it fairly well:

> (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
>    will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)

Just run it as root (e.g. `sudo netstat -np`)